# Missing Tizen Emulator Manager

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I installed the latest Tizen SDK (Tizen 2.4 SDK with IDE installer for Windows 64bit). Launching the Emulator Manager in the IDE gives the following error "Emulator Manager is not installed or the installation path is invalid." I searched my installation folder and can't find the Emulator Manager there. Therefore I conclude that the Emulator Manager is not included in the latest installation of the Tizen SDK.

I also checked the Update Manager, but can't find an URL with the Emulator Manager package. If the Emulator Manager was removed from the installation, how are we supposed to install it?

Comment: Same problem bro...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the update manager click on all packages and try to install it from there

Answer (score 5):

Open up Tizen Package Manager. Install Tizen SDK Tools - Emulation Manager. While there, you will probably want to install the emulators themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Tizen Studio -> tools -> Package Manager. Make sure you close the Tizen studio app after the package manager opens. Then install the required installers.